# Why does $I-S=I-QAQ^{-1}=Q(I-A)Q^{-1}$ hold for A being a diagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Why does $I-S=I-QAQ^{-1}=Q(I-A)Q^{-1}$ hold for A being a diagonal matrix? I saw this used in a proof and I can't bring myself to believe it. Note that S is also skew-hermitian if that makes a difference. So $S*=-S$.

Comment: Oh really? Why is this? It seems to break the order of operations...

Answer (score 1):

$I-QAQ^{-1}=QIQ^{-1}-QAQ^{-1}=Q(IQ^{-1}-AQ^{-1})=Q(I-A)Q^{-1}$

This holds for all matrices $A$, not just diagonal ones.

Comment: Oh thank you so much!